# How to detect whether the device is rooted or not?

Tags: android, root

My application is required to not to work on rooted device. I would like to know like how to detect it at run time within the app that the device in which app is running is rooted or not.

There are many links and I have applied all the possible ways but still at some rooted device I am not able to detect the device is rooted and my application is working I want to block the the rooted user from using my app.

Please kindly help

below is the peice of code that I have written.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();

if(new 
DeviceUtils().isDeviceRooted(getApplicationContext())){
showAlertDialogAndExitApp("This device is 
rooted. You can't use this app.");
}
}


public void showAlertDialogAndExitApp(String message) {

        AlertDialog alertDialog = new 
        AlertDialog.Builder(corporatefedmobile.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);
        alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void 
onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
finish();

}
}); 
alertDialog.show();
}

    public class DeviceUtils {

        public Boolean isDeviceRooted(Context context){
            boolean isRooted = isrooted1() || isrooted2() || 
                        isrooted4() || isrooted3() || isroot5() || 
                        isroot6();
            return isRooted;
        }

        private boolean isrooted1() {

            File file = new 
                            File("/system/app/Superuser.apk");
            if (file.exists()) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        // try executing commands
        private boolean isrooted2() {
            String[] paths = { "/system/app/Superuser.apk", 
                                            "/sbin/su", 
                                            "/system/bin/su", 
                                            "/system/xbin/su", 
                                            "/data/local/xbin/su", 
                                            "/data/local/bin/su", 
                                            "/system/sd/xbin/su",
                                "/system/bin/failsafe/su", 
                                            "/data/local/su", 
                                       "/su/bin/su"};
for (String path : paths) {
if (new File(path).exists())
return true;
}
return false;
}

private boolean isrooted3() {
Process process = null;
try {
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new 
String[] { "/system/xbin/which", "su" });
BufferedReader in = new 
BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
if (in.readLine() != null) return true;
return false;
} catch (Throwable t) {
return false;
} finally {
if (process != null) process.destroy();
}
}

private boolean isrooted4() {
String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;
return buildTags != null && 
 buildTags.contains("test-keys");
}
public boolean isRootAvailable(){
for(String pathDir : 
System.getenv("PATH").split(":")){
if(new File(pathDir, "su").exists()) {
return true;
}
}
return false;
}

public boolean isroot5(){
if (isRootAvailable()) {
Process process = null;
try {
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "id"});
BufferedReader in = new 
BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
String output = in.readLine();
if (output != null && 
output.toLowerCase().contains("uid=0"))
return true;
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
if (process != null)
process.destroy();
}
}

return false;
}

public  boolean isroot6()

{
String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;

if (buildTags != null && buildTags.contains("test-keys")) {

return true;
}

return false;
}
}
```

Comment: try this lib : https://github.com/scottyab/rootbeer

Comment: you will never be able to detect if the device is rooted for sure. In the end, root user always has more permissions than your app, therefore it will always be able to hide itself from your app.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the below method it will return true if your device is root access otherwise it will return false.

```
public static boolean isRooted() {

    // get from build info
    String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;
    if (buildTags != null && buildTags.contains("test-keys")) {
        return true;
    }

    // check if /system/app/Superuser.apk is present
    try {
        File file = new File("/system/app/Superuser.apk");
        if (file.exists()) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // ignore
    }

    // try executing commands
    //return canExecuteCommand("/system/xbin/which su")|| canExecuteCommand("/system/bin/which su") || canExecuteCommand("which su");
    if(!canExecuteCommand("su"))
        if(findBinary("su"))
            return true;
   return false;
}

public static boolean findBinary(String binaryName) {
    boolean found = false;
    if (!found) {
        String[] places = { "/sbin/", "/system/bin/", "/system/xbin/",
                "/data/local/xbin/", "/data/local/bin/",
                "/system/sd/xbin/", "/system/bin/failsafe/", "/data/local/" };
        for (String where : places) {
            if (new File(where + binaryName).exists()) {
                found = true;

                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return found;
}

// executes a command on the system
private static boolean canExecuteCommand(String command) {
    boolean executedSuccesfully;
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        executedSuccesfully = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        executedSuccesfully = false;
    }

    return executedSuccesfully;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to find the system files if you can rich them, then the system is rooted.

```
    boolean rooted = false;
    String[] places = {"/sbin/", "/system/bin/", "/system/xbin/", "/data/local/xbin/", "/data/local/bin/", "/system/sd/xbin/", "/system/bin/failsafe/", "/data/local/"};
    for (String where : places) {
         if (new File(where + binaryName).exists()) {
               rooted = true;
               break;
         }
     }
   }
return rooted;
```

Comment: what to write in binaryName variable ? Does  binaryName="su" ?

Comment: the binary file you will try to find is "su"

Comment: I have already implemented the method but in different login its not working